# How do I know current across unknown load if I know voltage

Tags: voltage, current

If I know voltage across a load, but don't know load resistance, how do I know current going through load?

Do I put a resistor of 1K and calculate?

My voltage is square wave so multimeter only get average current. I want current square wave

Comment: Are you asking for a theoretical answer?  Are you asking for practical current measurement techniques?  At the moment, the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: I am asking using actual multimeter and circuits. My signal is  square wave so multimeter only get average current. I want current square wave.

Comment: pls give details on square wave, 'known voltage' and average current read on multimeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serial resistor is OK, but it should be several orders of magnitude smaller than the load, so 1k is a little surprising. Also i would measure with oscilloscope instead relying on average and recovering peak out of it. And the best part: you cand use DC instead your square wave, just put external voltage source.

More generally there is a four - point measuremet method. You take two DVMs: one for current and one for voltage. It's normally used for power metering, but also for accurate resistance metering too.

Comment: how do I use oscilloscope to calculate current? if I use oscilloscope I can get peak-peak square wave voltage of load, but I don't know load resistance.

Comment: Of course you know the voltage, but across a known CURRENT SENSE RESISTOR. And according to kirhoff's law it's the same current.

Comment: So I put a 100 ohm resistor, and use oscilloscope to get voltage square wave across resistor, then calculate current?

Comment: Yes. But i would expect like 1Ohm or even 0.1Ohm. What current do you expect to see? Milliamps or amps?

Comment: about less than 10 mA. I tested with 100 ohm resistor and voltage signal is really noisy. using 1 ohm resistor can get more clear signal?

Comment: No, if it's 10mA, stay with 100 ohm. Make sure your GND lead is very short and close to the resistor. Also make sure that the resistor is on the minus side of the load, so the scope ground is not shorted to something else. And post a picture here please.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tested with a 1.5k load, and get clear square wave of 1V across 100 ohm, which is correct because my circuit is suppose to provide a constant current of 10mA across load with max 30v. when I use my actual load, 100 ohm wave is noisy, I guess is because my load is >3k ohm, so my circuit cannot provide 10mA

Comment: I am not satisfied with your explanation. If the resistance is too high, it doesn't usually cause noises. Just the current is lower. What is your load? Is it resistive or something active or inductive/capacitive?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a hall effect sensor to measure instantaneous current and a low end microcontroller to drive an output led or lcd panel.
The Allegro ACS 712 is fairly simple to use, and you can find breakout boards for it at low cost at sparkfun. 
datasheet here: http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS712-Datasheet.ashx?la=en

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a small* resistor in series with the load and then measure the voltage across it.

*the resistor has to be small enough so the voltage dropped across it is small compared to the voltage on the load, however, not so small so as to be impossible to measure.